# CDPieMenu (cocoapod) in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm trying to add [CDPieMenu](https://github.com/wokalski/CDPieMenu) to my swift project using a `.podspec` gist I found [here](https://gist.github.com/bartvandendriessche/4109860).

I downloaded the podspec locally & added it to my podfile like so:

```
  pod 'CDPieMenu', :path => '~/Documents/Project/CDPieMenu.podspec'
```

Here's the podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name     = 'CDPieMenu'
    s.version  = '0.1'
    s.license  = 'MIT License'
    s.summary  = 'Fully and easily customizable rotary wheel control also called pie menu for iPhone and iPad.'
    s.homepage = 'https://github.com/wczekalski/CDPieMenu'
    s.author   = { 'W. Czekalski'    => 'me@wczekalski.com' }

    s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/wczekalski/CDPieMenu.git', :commit => '2f49362' }
    s.source_files = 'Wheel'

    s.description = 'Fully and easily customizable rotary wheel control also called pie menu for iPhone and iPad.'
    'Very similar to the control in Convertbot. As the only one in the internet it rotates with inertia/mementum.'
    'Drawn using CoreGraphics without any images.'

    s.platform = :ios
    s.frameworks = 'AudioToolbox', 'QuartzCore'
    s.requires_arc = true
end
```

I ran `pod update` and everything worked fine and it seems to have been installed.

However, I'm unable to reference it from my project files now. 
Did I miss something?

## EDIT 1:

I forgot to mention I have already setup a bridging-header and added `CDPieMenu` headers to it.

Project-bridging-header:

```
#import "CDCircle.h"
#import "CDCircleGestureRecognizer.h"
#import "CDCircleOverlayView.h"
#import "CDCircleThumb.h"
#import "CDIconView.h"
#import "Common.h"
```

## EDIT 2:

I just checked and it seems the pod isn't installed at all. There isn't a `CDPieMenu` in the `Pods` directory. 
But `pod update` didn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two problems here, one of which I was able to resolve using @whatever38's suggestion, i.e. I was using `pod update` instead of `pod install`.

The other problem was that I needed to specify the path to my podspec file in my `Podfile`. I was doing this by specifying the `:path =>` parameter, whereas I should've instead used the `:podspec =>` parameter.
So, my `Podfile` entry for `CDPieMenu` should look like so:

```
pod 'CDPieMenu', :podspec => '~/Documents/Project/CDPieMenu.podspec'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try "pod install" instead of "pod update".

EDIT:

And don't forget to open your project using the .xcworkspace file.